# Pass an environment variable from grunt to a file

Tags: node.js, rest, gruntjs, environment-variables

Depending on the environment, I want to run HTTP requests in a js file to a URL or another.

For example, I have something like this:

- http://dev.url.com
- http://preprd.url.com
- http://prod.url.com

What I want is to execute the grunt file and specify the env, so the js file should read the option and make the requests to an URL or another.

For instance:

```
grunt default --env=prod
```

How can I say to the js file that the URL is the dev, preprd or prod one?

Answer (score 3):

Node.js API exposes [`process`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html) object, which stores environment variables inside its `env` property. Every environmental variable set before runtime will be inside `process.env`.

For example:

```
$ NODE_ENV=production node -e 'console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)'
```

will output:

```
production
```

In your particular case, you can use `process.env` inside your Gruntfile.js and then, when running grunt, you can use it like the example above.

#### Sample `Gruntfile.js` with environment variables

*Adapted from Grunt.js [website](https://gruntjs.com/sample-gruntfile)*

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    jshint: {
      files: ['Gruntfile.js', 'src/**/*.js', 'test/**/*.js'],
      options: {
        globals: {
          jQuery: true
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      files: ['<%= jshint.files %>'],
      tasks: process.env.PRODUCTION ? [] : ['jshint']
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint']);
};
```

Then, if you run

```
$ grunt watch # PRODUCTION environment variable is not set
```

it will execute `jshint` task when watching `files`. On the other hand, if you set the `PRODUCTION` variable and run the same command

```
$ PRODUCTION=true grunt watch
```

it won't execute any task when watching `files`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. So, if I have the variable stored in NODE_ENV, can I refer to it in a js file?

Comment: It does not have to be `NODE_ENV` specifically, you can name it as you like, as long as you access the variable with `process.env`.
_(I'll add another example to clarify this)_